# JavaScript: can't immediately select elements after creating them?

Tags: javascript, hoisting, nodelist

My script contains the following code that is causing me issues:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  if (!gamePlay) {
    setup()
    let word=document.querySelectorAll('box')
    console.log(word)
    btn.classList.toggle('hidden')
    gamePlay=true
  }
})
```

After all the `div` elements are created in the function `setup()`, I am trying to select them by their class name (`box`) however the node list from the section is an empty node list (which is also shown in the console).

I am assuming the code is synchronous. I just can't seem to access the elements created by the call to `setup()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are able to access and query document elements immediately after they are created.

The issue here is that you selector syntax is incorrect; to select the elements with `box` class, prefix the selector with a ".":

```
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {

  if (!gamePlay) {

    setup();

    let word = document.querySelectorAll('.box'); // Prefix .
    console.log(word);
    btn.classList.toggle('hidden');

    gamePlay = true;
  }
})
```